# Django instance variables in custom form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I run into a weird behaviour (in my opinion) when using a custom forms.ChoiceField.
Here is my code:

```
class ChoiceField2(forms.ChoiceField):

def __init__(self, *, choices=(), **kwargs):
    super().__init__(choices=choices, **kwargs)

    # Init in constructor
    #self._mydata = []

def add(self, val):
    # Init outside constructor
    #if not hasattr(self, "_mydata"):
    #    self._mydata = []
    
    self._mydata.append(val)
    pprint(self._mydata)


class Create2(FormView):

form_class = f.MyForm # this is the form that uses ChoiceField2

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = self.form_class()
    import datetime
    form.fields["my_field"].add(datetime.datetime.now())
    return form
```

Now, when I initiate self._mydata in the constructor, at every page refresh data is constantly being added to self._mydata - it behaves basically as if it is a static variable.

If I initiate self._mydata outside the constructor (in the add method for example)
my datetime object is added only once - that is self._mydata contains only one object -
as expected in my opinion since the whole thing is created at each refresh!

Has anyone run into this before? What is the use case here? Should we not use __ init __ to create instance variables?